# Фильтрация продуктов по дополнительным полям или параметрам модификаций

Tags: мойсклад-api

Хотелось бы узнать возможно ли фильтровать через JSON API по заполненности дополнительных полей и/или параметрам модификации? (как это можно делать на сайте - скрин ниже)

[image: пример фильтров на сайте]

Answer (score 1):

В соответствии с [документацией](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/#header-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-filter) по дополнительным полям фильтравать нельзя, но можно отфильтровать по параметрам модификации. При [запросе](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/#%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-get) модификаций, у них выводится поле product, в котором указана метаданные товара. Соответственно, если необходимо получить товары, то можно запросить список модификаций с фильтром по нужному параметру, а из полученного списка модификаций вытащить product.
Пример запроса:

```
https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.2/entity/variant?filter=name=test&expand=product
```